# How can i properly initialize a UITableViewCell

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am wondering how to properly initialize my cells, because while they render perfectly smooth + quick for initially loaded simple cells, there is a significant hickup when scrolling through more complex types.

Since those cells also scroll smoothly after having been visible once, i suspect that there is some initialization done which happens when a cell is being shown for the first time.

Essentially i want to artifically mirror whatever the platform is doing, while the application is idle, to prevent the user from experiencing this hickup.

Unfortunately i can't seem to get this done perfect just yet.

While the GetCell part call already smoothens that hickup significantly, there is still a slight fps drop when a cell is being shown for the first time.

Here's what i've tried (Note that commented out parts had little impact on speeding up initialization.):

```
public void Prefetch(int start, int range)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(nameof(Prefetch));
            var current = start;
            var end = start + range;
            var tv = GetTableView();
            while (current < ItemsSource.Count && current < end)
            {
                if (_prefetchedCellIndices.Contains(current))
                {
                    current++;
                    continue;
                }

                var cell = GetCell(tv, NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(current, 0));
//              cell.SetNeedsLayout();
//              cell.LayoutIfNeeded();
//              cell.SetNeedsUpdateConstraints();
//              cell.UpdateConstraintsIfNeeded();
//              cell.Init();
                current++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Personally I would avoid "pre-creating" a cell for every data element in your item source, for a few cells, ok, but once the numbers of data elements exceeds the visual number of cells in your UITableView you are trying to mask an underlaying issue with poor use of memory and cpu for cell creation and storage that the user might never need. I would instrument what in your cell creation within `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is causing your root issue and focus on correcting that first before trying go down the path of prefetching cells that user might see next if they scroll down/up...

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on what you're trying to display in the more complex cells. For example it doesn't use too many resources to reuse UIControls such as buttons, UISwitches etc, if there is already a cell with the same reuseidentifier ready for the tableview to populate. In my experience, some of the more resource intensive elements to populate are UIImageViews for example, where you might be getting the Image from a URL. What I Would strongly advise is that you should create array's or lists of whatever data you need to use to populate the cells in question, and then use the IndexPath.Row to grab them. Try to 'predownload' Images from URL's etc. It might be worth taking a look at the documentation on Xamarin's developer site, as they acknowledge table views as an element that may require a developers attention to optimise.

[Xamarin Optimisation Page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/performance/)

Note: I wouldn't try to 'pre cache' the cells as iOS already does that hence the 'reuse identifier'. I would simply try to 'pre-cache' any data that could take a while to display.